# scraping from multiple url

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
#scraping data
page=requests.get('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/11860/0000011860-00-000025.txt')
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
data_1=list(soup.children)[8]
main_data=list(data_1.children)[1].get_text()

#number of words
num=len(main_data.split())
```

this is my successful code to calculate total number of words from a single URL. now the challenge is to calculate number of words from a csv file which has got 500 urls in a column. i tried a lot but failed.

Comment: what's the relation between scraping and counting words in CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

For parsing csv, there's the csv library, so you'd simply need:

```
import csv

with open('yourfile.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
  reader = csv.reader(csvfile) # add delimiter ='',quotechar ='' depending on csv structure
  for URL in reader: 
    page = requests.get(URL)
    #the rest of what you want to do with the content of URL
```

You could put your current code into a function and then call it for each parsed URL.

Comment: for url in reader:

Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)     *i am getting this error*

Comment: Sorry about that, Didn't look into it extensively. try. " open('yourfile.csv', "rt", encoding="utf8" ) " and if that does not work, "ascii" (basically, guessing the encoding). This should open the file in text mode with a specific encoding and should parse links as strings.